# Automate Opera Mini Tests via Appium/Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, appium, opera

I have researched how to test mobile web apps via Appium (to use the mobile sdk)
The achieve automation of opera browser tests, one can use selenium / appium with the opera chrome or presto drivers (imported libraries)

However there is no documentation with regards to running automation on opera mini applications.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Has anyone successfully used Apium to test Opera Mini?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is [not supported](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/blob/master/docs/appium.md) out of the box by Appium (CHROME, CHROMIUM, SAFARI are listed), you can use [operachromiumdriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/blob/master/docs/appium.md):

```
desired_caps['chromedriverExecutable'] = '/absolute/path/to/operadriver'
desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('opera-browser.apk')
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.opera.browser'
desired_caps['androidDeviceSocket'] = desired_caps['appPackage'] + '.devtools'
```

Comment: Indeed this is what I had suspected, I may as well setup and test this and report back here. :) 

Thanks though dmie, from all documentation I could find, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to use the opera driver to automate tests on the opera browser on android, however, it was unable to provide the functionality needed to automate testing on the opera mini browser on android.